# Error while trying to upgrade SQL Server 2008 (SP2) to SQL Server 2012: There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting LICENSEPATH

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade one of our SQL Server Enterprise (2008 (SP2)) to 2012. I am using the upgrade option but it gives me the following error:

> Error Code 0x85640002: There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting LICENSEPATH

We have downloaded the image from our Volume Licensing account. Also, the same image was used to install SQL 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2 servers without any issues.

Below is the install `summary.txt`. I have tried everywhere but no go. Would really appreciate any assistance.

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2057043966
  Exit facility code:            1380
  Exit error code:               2
  Exit message:                  There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting LICENSEPATH.
  Start time:                    2014-02-28 10:58:49
  End time:                      2014-02-28 10:58:58
  Requested action:              RunRules
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0x0BA02FC6%400x294A9FD9&EvtType=0x0BA02FC6%400x294A9FD9

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  xxxxxxx
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2008 R2
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     U.A.E.
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         D:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        RunRules
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  ENU:                           true
  FEATURES:                      
  HELP:                          false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         true
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  RULES:                         GlobalRules
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20140228_105848\ConfigurationFile.ini

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               The rule result report file is not available.

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException
    Message:
        There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting LICENSEPATH.
    HResult : 0x85640002
        FacilityCode : 1380 (564)
        ErrorCode : 2 (0002)
    Data:
      SettingId = LICENSEPATH
      WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingApplicabilityException@2
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack:
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.BootstrapExtension.ValidateChainerSettingAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun, ServiceContainer context)
    Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingValueException
        Message:
                There was a failure to calculate the default value of setting LICENSEPATH.
        HResult : 0x85640001
                FacilityCode : 1380 (564)
                ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
        Data:
          SettingId = LICENSEPATH
          WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CalculateSettingValueException@1
        Stack:
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting`1.CalculateValue()
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallQueuedSubscriberDelegates()
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.Publish(Publisher publisher)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting.CalculateApplicability()
        Inner exception type: System.ArgumentException
            Message:
                        Culture ID 3072 (0x0C00) is not a supported culture.
                        Parameter name: culture
            Stack:
                        at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
                        at System.Globalization.CultureTable.GetCultures(CultureTypes types)
                        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.LcidUtilities.GetLangPackParentFolderForLcid(String lcid)
                        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.LcidUtilities.GetLcidFolder(ServiceContainer context, String baseFolderFullPath)
                        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.LicensePathSetting.DefaultValue()
                        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Deployment.PrioritizedPublishing.PublishingQueue.CallFunctionWhileAutosubscribing[T](SubscriberDelegate subscriberDelegate, Int32 priority, AutosubscribingFunctionDelegate`1 function)
                        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Setting`1.CalculateValue()
```

Regards,

Mohammed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of MVP figured out the root cause of the error and I would like to share it. 
We had custom culture installed on the server which is used for Epic Application Reporting where in the regional settings was set to English (U.A.E.). I reverted the regional settings of the OS to English (United States) and the error disappeared. However, the setup files seems to be corrupt as I am getting the file format error. I will copy the ISO directly on the server and extract it via WinRAR as suggested.

Regards
Mohammed

Comment: This is what worked for me, but couldnt upgrade at all without features failing.

Comment: You're correct, but what happens if you revert to your original regional settings?